# Call to undefined method Imagick::writeImageFile()

Tags: php, imagemagick, ubuntu-10.04, imagick

I've a problem with Imagick - PHP.
I've this code :

```
function createImages ($src, $dst, $width, $height)
{
        $image = new Imagick($src);
        $image->stripImage();

        $color = new ImagickPixel();
        $color->setColor('rgb(255,255,255)');
        if(resizeimage($image, $width, $height)) {
            $image->borderimage($color, 
            intval(($width - $image->getimagewidth()) / 2), 
            intval(($height - $image->getimageheight()) / 2));
            $image1 = new Imagick();
            $image1->newImage($width, $height, new ImagickPixel('white'));
            $image1->setImageColorspace($image->getImageColorspace());
            $image1->compositeImage($image, $image1->getImageCompose(), 0, 0);
            $image1->setImageCompressionQuality(90);
            $image1->setimagecompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
            $image1->setformat('jpeg');
            $fileHandle = fopen($dst, "w");
            $image1->writeImageFile($fileHandle);
            $color->destroy();
            $image1->destroy();
        }           
        $image->destroy();
        return true;
}
```

And this error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Imagick::writeImageFile()

I don't understand why all other methods work good, but not writeImageFile(). Can you help me please?

Comment: Do you know which version of Imagemagick you're using?

Comment: `dpkg -p imagemagick ` give 7:6.5.7.8-1ubuntu1.3

Comment: Here's another guess - can you check the value of `ini_get("disable_functions")`to see if exec is disabled? (Not sure if it would throw an undefined error if this were the issue, though...)

Comment: disable_functions = no value :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **writeImageFile** function is available in ImageMagick version 6.3.6, so perhaps your version is not recent enough? There is also **writeImage** which may be a usable alternative in your case: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimage.php

Comment: Yeah good answer, it's ok now, i use **writeImage** and not **writeImageFile** and it works! Thank you all.